# comment system using php inside the body , and there is error on the result

Tags: php, html, database, wamp, notepad++

i am wrinting this code below in notepad and i saved in .html extent , 
i want to design a simple comment system with a database (which is notepad ) to save the comments , but when i click on the submit button it apears there is error in an specific command which is `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` . can you help me ?

```
<html>
<body>
<div class ="forumform">
<form method="POST" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">
name: <input type=text name="name" id="name">
comment: <input type=text name="commentcontent" id="commentcontent">
<button type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" class="btn">submit</button>
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Have you tried without using short tags? `<?php echo` instead  `<?=`

Comment: FYI, Dont use `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` its vulnerable to XSS if not protected by htmlspecialchars(), if you want to post back to itself, then use `action=""`

Answer (score 0):

Did you say: `"i am wrinting this code below in notepad and i saved in .html extent"`?

PHP commands/scripts like the `<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>`, only run in files with`.php` ententions only!! not on HTML.

YOU should change the extension of your file, with the above script to `.php`

Answer (score 0):

you are using the php echo shortcut make sure it is enabled in your php.ini file  serach for this **short_open_tag** and enable it or simply use `<?php echo .... ?>` instead of `<?= ... ?>`